# How to ensure that a string parameter to a function is not empty?

Tags: string, solidity-0.5.x

Lets say that I have a function which needs two string parameter ,

```
function data(string memory _firstname, string memory _lastname) public {
buyer[msg.sender] = Buyer(_firstname, _lastname);
}
```

Now, I want to ensure that user has not left either of the two fields empty. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular function you can use the following validation:

```
require(_firstname.length && _lastname.length, "There is empty string passed as parameter.");
```

This is only checking if the strings have at least one symbol inside of them, if you want to have maximum symbols length validation then you have to add it as condition.

Comment: Sorry , Error : TypeError: Member "length" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in string memory.

Comment: @Ashishkumar which solidity version are u using?

Answer (score 0):

```
require(bytes(_firstname).length >0, "First name cannot be left empty");
require(bytes(_lastname).length >0, "Last name cannot be left empty");
```

But, I still want to make it a one line code !

Comment: ....).length > 0 && bytes(_lastname).length > 0, “message”);